# Is EDR the same as NGAV (next gen antivirus)?

Tags: antivirus

I have searched online and still do not fully understand. Some sites treat them as different and others treat them as if they are the same.

Can anyone please tell me if they are the same?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These are marketing terms often oriented towards relatively non-technical customers which lends them to being corrupted to the point of meaningless.

If you are looking to purchase one of these solutions I would recommend conducting a proof of concept (POC) with a few different vendors. Before you start you should consider what features are important to you besides "catching malware."

Keep in mind these solutions are most useful against less sophisticated attackers and are best used when there is an individual or team to evaluate alerts as they are generated.